# Mean weight of $m$ boys; find $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mean-square-error

Mean weight of m boys is $43$ kg. If the teacher who weighs $63$kg is included the mean becomes $45$ kg. What is the value of $m$?

Comment: Yes m is a number of boys

Comment: This is not a 'do my homework for free' service!!!

Comment: Where are you struggling with this question?

Comment: How further this equation is elaborate?
(∑xi+63)/(m+1)=45

Comment: I have solved it. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $\sum{x_i}$ and $m$:

$\sum{x_i}/m=43$ and $(\sum{x_i} +63)/(m+1)=45$

Comment: Obviously giving $m=9$!

Comment: could you please explain more?